# Jupyter: Creating Notebook Failed and Error loading notebook

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm having a few issues with Jupyter notebooks.

First, the application seems to be "Not Trusted", and clicking "Trust" when prompted fails to do anything:

[image]

Second, the following error when trying to create a new Jupyter notebook:

```
Creating Notebook Failed:

The error was: Unexpected error while saving file: Desktop/Complete-Python-3-Bootcamp-master/03-Methods and Functions/Untitled.ipynb database is locked
```

Third, if I try to load other Jupyter notebooks, I get problems.  For example, trying to open 03-Function Practice Exercises.ipynb from "Python Bootcamp" in Jupyter

[image] I get the following:

```
Error loading notebook
An unknown error occurred while loading this notebook. This version can load notebook formats or earlier. See the server log for details.
```

The jupyer_mac.command terminal logs:

```
[W 14:40:06.678 NotebookApp] Notebook Desktop/Complete-Python-3-Bootcamp-master/03-Methods and Functions/04-Function Practice Exercises - Solutions.ipynb is not trusted
```

And:

```
[E 14:57:45.839 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/contents/Desktop/Complete-Python-3-Bootcamp-master/03-Methods%20and%20Functions/03-Function%20Practice%20Exercises.ipynb?type=notebook&_=1562536665698 (::1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8890', method='GET', uri='/api/contents/Desktop/Complete-Python-3-Bootcamp-master/03-Methods%20and%20Functions/03-Function%20Practice%20Exercises.ipynb?type=notebook&_=1562536665698', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 112, in get
    path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content,
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 433, in get
    model = self._notebook_model(path, content=content)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 392, in _notebook_model
    self.mark_trusted_cells(nb, path)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 503, in mark_trusted_cells
    trusted = self.notary.check_signature(nb)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 439, in check_signature
    return self.store.check_signature(signature, self.algorithm)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 239, in check_signature
    (datetime.utcnow(), algorithm, digest),
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
[W 14:57:45.840 NotebookApp] Unhandled error
```

This only recently started happening, and I don't know why. It seems like both these errors (not being able to create a new notebook and not being able to open existing notebooks) is stemming from some sort of permissions issue.  I should not that some notebook files from the list in the image above can be opened with no problems.

Comment: have you figured it out ?